# Existence of unit and counit from Hom-sets correspondence

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal {C,D:Cat}$ be locally small categories for simplicity, and $L:\mathcal{C\rightarrow D}$ and $R:\mathcal{D\rightarrow C}$ functors.

Let $F:\mathcal{C\times D}\rightarrow Set$ be a bifunctor with $F\ (c,d) := Hom_{\mathcal D}\ (L\ c, d)$,

$G:\mathcal{C\times D}\rightarrow Set$ also be a bifunctor with $G\ (c,d) := Hom_{\mathcal C}\ (c, R\ d)$

and $\alpha:F\cong G$ a (bi-)natural isomorphism between the two.

tldr; $L\dashv R$.

**The question:** I want to construct the unit and counit from this definition.

We can define in components

$\eta_c := \alpha_{(c,L\ c)}\ id\ :\ c\rightarrow(R\circ L)\ c$  and

$\varepsilon_d := \alpha^{-1}_{(R\ d, d)}\ id\ :\ (L\circ R)\ d\rightarrow d$,

and prove these are indeed natural transformations.

But how can I prove that $(\varepsilon\circ L)\ \circ\ (L\circ\eta) = id$  ?

(Let's focus on this identity since the other one is analogous.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naturality of $\alpha$ lets us say

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Hom_D\ \big((L\circ R)\ d, d\big) @<{\alpha^{-1}_{(R\ d, d)}}<< Hom_C\ \big(R\ d, R\ d\big)\\
@V g\ \circ\_\circ\ L\ f VV @VV R\ g\ \circ\_\circ\ f V \\
Hom_D\ \big(L\ c, L\ c\big) @<<{\alpha^{-1}_{(c, L\ c)}}< Hom_C\ \big(c, (R\circ L)\ c\big)
\end{CD}$$

for $f:c\rightarrow R\ d$ and $g:d\rightarrow L\ c$.

In particular if $d = L\ c$ we can use $f:=\eta_c$ and $g:=id_{L\ c}$ and we get
$$ \varepsilon_{L\ c}\circ L\ \eta_c
= g \circ \big(\alpha^{-1}_{((R\circ L)\ c,L\ c)}\ id_{R\ d}\big) \circ L\ f
= \alpha^{-1}_{(c,L\ c)}\ \big(R\ g \circ id_{R\ d} \circ f\big)
= id_{L\ c}
$$